# chmod() and chown() of a symlink file in PHP

Tags: php, filesystems

Are there PHP commands to change file access permissions/owner of a symlink file as opposed to those of the object the symlink points to?

From the shell I can

```
$ mkdir adir
$ ln -s adir alink
$ chmod 0700 alink         -- changes permissions of directory adir
$ chmod -h 0700 alink      -- changes permissions of file alink
```

but I don't see how to do the last of these in PHP other than by invoking a shell, e.g. with `exec()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP does not support changing the permissions of symbolic links (there is no `lchmod` function like the [`lstat`](http://php.net/lstat) and [`lchown`](http://php.net/lchown) functions).

Linux [doesn't support it](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-coreutils@gnu.org/msg17785.html), either:

> POSIX does not require lchmod, and Linux does not supply it.  On platforms that 
>   lack lchmod, symlinks always have the same default permissions, so the 
>   inability to change permissions is not a problem because the source that you 
>   would be copying has the same permissions (0777) as the newly created symlink 
>   destination.
>
> On BSD, where lchmod is supported, only the 0555 bits matter (readlink() fails 
>   if the current user can't read the symlink, and all other syscalls fail with 
>   ENOENT for failure to follow the symlink if the current user can't 
>   search/execute the symlink during file name resolution), and even then, only if 
>   on a file system mounted with the symperm option.